# Python automate user tasks in kvm-qemu/remote-viewer

Tags: python, kvm

I'm working on a simple script to automate a repetitive task of starting a virtual machine, finding it's spice tcp port and starting remote-viewer to interact with the virtual machine. The commands in sequence are:

```
virsh -c qemu:///system start test_machine
virsh -c qemu:///system domdisplay test_machine
```

This outputs something like: spice://127.0.0.1:5903. The third command is:

```
remote-viewer spice://127.0.0.1:5903
```

In python 2.7.5 on RHEL 7 I have the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import pipes

machine_name = 'test_machine'

return_code = subprocess.check_output(['virsh', '-c', 'qemu:///system', 'start', machine_name])
return_code = subprocess.check_output(['virsh', '-c', 'qemu:///system', 'domdisplay', machine_name])
print str(return_code)
esc_return_code = pipes.quote(return_code)
print "remote-viewer {}".format(return_code)
#proc = subprocess.check_output(["remote-viewer {}".format(esc_return_code)]) #, return_code])
```

The first two of my commands work as expected--it's the third command with remote-viewer that throws an error.

I've tried a few different things thinking it was special characters causing a problem but now that I see the first two commands working just fine I'm not convinced. I also tried the same format as the first two commands like this:

```
subprocess.check_output(['remote-viewer', return_code])
```

Running the script as is gives the output:

```
spice://127.0.0.1:5903

remote-viewer spice://127.0.0.1:5903

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/data/Scripts/runvm.py", line 13, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.check_output(["remote-viewer {}".format(esc_return_code)]) #, return_code]) 
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If I hard code the values (no variables) it works. Like this:

```
subprocess.check_output(['remote-viewer spice://127.0.0.1:5903'])
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Popen and shell=True to run the command

```
From subprocess import Popen
output='spice://127.0.0.1:5903'
Command='remote-viewer'+' '+output
#Proc=Popen(Command,shell=True)
Proc=Popen(Command)
```

Comment: This definitely works. Is there a safer way to do it? As I understand shell could be misused in this way. I would like to at minimum use the escaped version of the command with pipes.quote() but that doesn't seem to work--back to "No such file or directory".

Comment: if you dont wish to use shell=True , have a look on below link where commands have been launched on windows and Ubuntu without Shell=True  https://github.com/pankajigec26/Multiplatfrom_server_launcher/blob/master/handling_process.py